# Matching arrays and update value in array one

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to to update the value of array one, if it is found within array two, e.g:

```
$all_pets = ['Cat' => 0, 'Dog' => 0, 'Bird' => 0, 'Rabbit' => 0, 'Fish' => 0];
$user_has = ['Cat', 'Fish'];
```

I need to get the data back as:

```
$has_pets = ['Cat' => 1, 'Dog' => 0, 'Bird' => 0, 'Rabbit' => 0, 'Fish' => 1];
```

I've tried playing with the `array_intersect()` function and a foreach loop but for the life of me I could not get it working.

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use `foreach` to loop thru the array `$user_has`. Use `isset()` to check if the key exist in `$all_pets`. If it does, change the value.

```
$all_pets = ['Cat' => 0, 'Dog' => 0, 'Bird' => 0, 'Rabbit' => 0, 'Fish' => 0];
$user_has = ['Cat', 'Fish']; 

foreach( $user_has as $value ) {
    if ( isset( $all_pets[ $value ] ) ) $all_pets[ $value ]++;
}
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [Cat] => 1
    [Dog] => 0
    [Bird] => 0
    [Rabbit] => 0
    [Fish] => 1
)
```

Comment: guys consider that the user may has 2 cats and 1 dog, so you should increment the duplicates

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_merge()` and `array_count_values()`:

```
array_merge($all_pets, array_count_values($user_has));
```

#### [Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/OOgMj)

`array_count_values()` counts the occurrences of each value in the array, and returns an array with `value => count` pairs.

`array_merge()` merges the arrays, if they have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach and in_array()

```
$all_pets = ['Cat' => 0, 'Dog' => 0, 'Bird' => 0, 'Rabbit' => 0, 'Fish' => 0];
$user_has = ['Cat', 'Fish']; 
foreach($all_pets as $key=>$value){
    if(in_array($key,$user_has){
        $indexes = array_keys($user_has,$key); 
        $all_pets[$key]= count($indexes);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the user has 2 cats and 1 dog, you should increment the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$all_pets = ['Cat' => 0, 'Dog' => 0, 'Bird' => 0, 'Rabbit' => 0, 'Fish' => 0];
$user_has = ['Cat', 'Fish']; 


$has_pets = array();

foreach ($user_has as $key => $pet) {
    $has_pets[$pet]++;
}

print_r(array_merge($all_pets, $has_pets));
?>
```